# Crystal Report - Load report failed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net-2.0, reporting, windows

I am using Crystal Report (10.2.3600.0) in Windows Application using c#.net 2.0.

I have deployed the application in many of the clients machine. Until recently it was found out that in one of the machine the report is not working.

From the log file following error is shown -

> StackTrace:    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod,
>   Int16 parentJob)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod)
>   at
>   FlexiPackOfficeAutomation.frmJobCardViewer.PopulateReportFields()
>     InnerException: The system cannot
>   find the path specified.

One important thing which i noticed in that machine is that there is no C Drive. The windows is installed in H: Drive. I am not sure whether this is causing the issue.

The code which i am using to load the report is as follows,

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument JobCard1 = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();


cFPWebService objWS = new cFPWebService();

//Get the Job Details from the Webservice
DataSet mDsJobDetails = objWS.ObjWebService.GetJobDetails_ForCrystalReport(this._JobID);

string FileName = "rassdk://" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\reports\JobCard.rpt";
//Load the Crystal Report File
JobCard1.Load(FileName, CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy);
//Set the reportsource of the Crystal Report Viewer as this JobCard
crvJobCard.ReportSource = JobCard1;
```

I have tried the following on the clients machine

1. Reinstalled the crystal report Runtime
2. Reinstalled the software

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Search the entire registry for "Crystal". You'll find a key or two that is probably incorrect in pointing to the v10 DLLs on the C drive.

If you'll update the registry keys to the correct H drive location, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. Let me try this out on the clients machine directly.

Comment: I checked the clients machine and unfortunately i couldn't find any key in the registry which is pointing to C Drive.


I found 2-3 Keys which had the value "H:\Documents and Settings\CKSHASHI\Desktop\CrystalReportModule(32 Bit)\"
The Keynames were InstallSource & LastUsedSource.

the strange thing is that there is no folder called
"H:\Documents and Settings\CKSHASHI\Desktop\CrystalReportModule(32 Bit)\" in the system.


Any suggestions for me.

Comment: Did you search keys, values (everything)? You should find more than that with "Crystal" in it. What are you using to install the runtimes?

Comment: I have created a setup project and added the merge module "CrystalReportsRedist2005_x86.msm" to the setup project. This setup project is different from the actual Application setup. So i ask to install this in the system which needs reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Found this troubleshooting [document](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/d02f7cd3-f18b-2d10-55ad-dab2200f68fc?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&53240414858625) at SAP.  Looks like there's a section on installs without a C: drive.  The relevant section:

> Missing “C:\” drive
>   The application is deployed to a computer that does not have a “C:” drive. When the Crystal Reports runtime is installed via the msm or msi files, certain registry values are set to point to the C: drive. To resolve this issue modify registry values in the Registry Editor. ...
>
> At minimum, it will be necessary to modify the following string values:
>
> - CommonFiles
> - Path
> - ConnectionDirectoryPath
> - ChartSupportpath
> - ReportDirectoryPath
>
> The location of these string values varies depending on the version of Crystal Reports used. Search the registry on the development computer and study the appropriate keys. Modify as needed on the runtime computer.
>
> To troubleshoot these issues, a utility such as Process Monitor will prove useful.

This wasn't my issue, but perhaps this will help.